# Windows Phone 8 WCF Synchronous

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I have an app for WP8 and I would like to generate the reference to the services to call it synchronous instead of asynchronous. I need to make sure that one step is completed before start the second step.

Is there any way to do this ?

I've try to generate the methods sync instead of asynchronous but this option is not allowed in VS2013.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve, what you have mentioned, by using async/await keywords too, what you have to do is `await` the first method before calling the next method. That's it (*provided Step1 is properly implemented - you got your all the required stuff done for the next step to be taken*).

Suppose :-

Step1 method :-

```
public async Task Step1()
{
...
}
```

Step2 method :-

```
public async Task Step2()
{
...
}
```

Now you want to call the `Step2` only after completing of `Step1`.So, Just call them in order by awaiting the Step1 method(Task)

```
Public async Task/Void RunStep2AfterStep1()
{
  await Step1();
  // you will only get here only when you Step1() is completed successfully.
  await Step2();
}
```

The below 
[**Async/Await helper**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) Image give you proper flow of async/await.

[image]

**Note**:- Don't try to avoid the Async/Await they are much more powerful than you think, and if you think your requirement can't be fulfilled without them. Then, I think, you need to explore much.

Thanks :)

Comment: When I generate the service reference I need to assign the Async and Completed methods on my WP form. How can I use the async/await methodology in this cenario ?

Comment: @JuniorThurler please ask a new question with more details, i'm not sure about it. So that other people can also look into your problem.